# Get other apps permission realtime on Android

Tags: android, permissions

I'd like to get Permissions of a to-be-installed app (an app on Google Play), i.e. monitoring permissions of the apps that user is going to install.
PackageManager can do this but with the list of installed app.
How can I do this with the to-be-installed app?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get that.  If you want to assume the app is on Play and the user passes you the package name, you could download its webpage and screen scrape the info.  But there's no callback to be alerted when a user is installing an app and it wouldn't work for sideloads.